# What is the process of a fighter becoming an Eldritch Knight?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, fighter

According to the Pathfinder Core Rule-book, the requirements to become an Eldritch knight are:

- Weapon Proficiency - Must be proficient with all martial weapons
- Spells - Able to cast 3rd-level arcane spells

Because my character is a Fighter, he already has the weapon proficiency, so my question is: How do I go about meeting the second requirement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your character needs to be multiclassed.  Take enough levels of [an arcane spellcasting class](https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=006680642033474972217%3A6zo0hx_wle8&q=arcane%20spells#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=%22arcane%20spells%22&gsc.sort=&gsc.ref=more%3Aclasses) to be able to cast 3rd-level spells.

From the descriptive text for the [Prestige Class Eldritch Knight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/eldritch-knight),

> Because the road to becoming an eldritch knight requires both martial prowess and arcane power, eldritch knights almost always begin their paths as multiclassed characters, such as fighter/wizards or ranger/sorcerers.